# What is the maximum number of tool proficiencies a character can gain?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, equipment, proficiency

For the purposes of this question, we're going to ignore the rules, found in either the *Player's Handbook* (pg. 187) or *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* (pg. 134), that allow a character to learn a tool proficiency as part of their adventure downtime. For our purposes, we assume that these methods of gaining tool proficiencies are not available to us.

So given that constraint and the constraints below, what is the maximum quantity of tool proficiencies a character can learn as part of their normal progression?

The constraints:

- Only officially published 5th Edition sourcebooks
- No Unearthed Arcana, <strike>however tempting it might be to include the newly released Artificer revision</strike> *there is an officially released version of the Artificer, and that is valid.*
- Temporary effects, i.e. tool proficiencies gained from from spells should only be included if the character in question is capable of applying/maintaining said effects themselves.
- No proficiencies gained from magic items
- No use of downtime activities to learn new proficiencies (PHB pg. 187 or *Xanathar's* pg. 134)

Comment: Related: [How to optimize a character for the greatest number of skill proficiencies with the fewest number of levels?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/120807/how-to-optimize-a-character-for-the-greatest-number-of-skill-proficiencies-with), [How do I learn new tool proficiencies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73598/how-do-i-learn-new-tool-proficiencies)

Answer (score 10):

## 12 Tool Proficiencies, 15 if you count musical instruments, 16 if you also include gaming sets.

Let's take this piece at a time.

#### Race

Human with the Prodigy Feat, Envoy Warforged, Rock Gnome, or Dwarf. Nets +1 Tool Proficiencies.

#### Background

Any House Agent background (Eberron), except Kundarak, Medani, or Tharashk (Because those grant Thieves Tools, which is a waste of a slot) Nets +2 Tool Proficiencies

#### Feats

Skilled, obviously. +3 Tool Proficiencies. That's the only feat that grants Tool Proficiencies, and you cannot take it more than once.

#### Classes

Bard: 1 level IF you are counting musical instruments. They get 3 Musical Instrument proficiencies at level 1. This must be your First Class, or you only get 1 musical instrument

Rogue: 3 Levels, Mastermind. +3 Tool Proficiencies (Thieves' Tools, Disguise Kit, Forgery Kit) and +1 gaming set

Cleric: 1 level, Forge Domain. +1 Tool Proficiency (Smith's Tools) OR Knowledge Domain (Channel Divinity to gain temporary access to Proficiency with any 1 Tool)

Monk: 3 levels, Drunken Master. +1 Tool Proficiency (Brewer's supplies) OR Kensei (Calligrapher or Painter's Tools)

Fighter: 3 levels, Battlemaster. +1 Tool Proficiency (Your Choice)

#### Spells

There are no spells that grant temporary proficiency. The only magical effect that lets you 'fake' proficiency is found in the Knowledge Domain Cleric, which only lasts for 10 minutes (not long enough for a major project), but it's a choice between that one, and a Forge Domain cleric (which grants a permanent proficiency). So, do you want short term flexibility, or a full proficiency?

Comment: Could probably add the Vedalken (*Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, pg. 21) to the race list, since they also gain a single Tool proficiency as part of their Racial features.

Comment: It might be helpful to cite the sourcebook for things from outside the PHB/core books (e.g. Eberron content).

Answer (score 7):

### With *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, 24 tool proficiencies

If you really want to maximize tool proficiencies, it'll involve a lot of multiclass levels. You'll want to make sure you have at least a 13 ability score in each of Charisma, Wisdom, Intelligence, and Dexterity. This should be feasible with the standard array or with point buy, given the new rules in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*: Customizing Your Origin -> Ability Score Increases for applying the Dwarf (Mountain)'s **Ability Score Increase** to the appropriate ability scores.

(However, a straight-classed Dwarven Artificer can still get access to 13 tool proficiencies by level 4, which is still a *lot* without any silly ability score spreads or even any need for multiclass rules to be allowed.)

#### At Level 1: 12 tool proficiencies

##### Race (7 tool proficiencies)

Choose the Dwarf (Mountain) race. It grants **Tool Proficiency** (1 tool proficiency), **Dwarven Combat Training** (4 weapon proficiencies), and **Dwarven Armor Training** (2 armor proficiencies). Use the rules in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*: Customizing Your Origin -> Proficiencies to swap each weapon and armor proficiency for a different tool proficiency. You can choose any tool, making these true "wildcard" tool proficiencies.

*Note: don't choose smith's tools, thieves' tools, tinker's tools, disguise kit, forgery kit, or the last gaming set if you're following this build the whole way!*

- Smith’s tools, Brewer’s supplies, or Mason’s tools.
- Wildcard
- Wildcard
- Wildcard
- Wildcard
- Wildcard
- Wildcard

##### Background (2 tool proficiencies)

Use the rules in *Player's Handbook*: Backgrounds -> Customizing a Background to customize any background by choosing two tool proficiencies from the sample backgrounds. Note that these aren't full "wildcard" tool proficiencies because not every tool is represented in the sample backgrounds.

*Note: don't choose smith's tools, thieves' tools, tinker's tools, disguise kit, forgery kit, or the last gaming set if you're following this build the whole way!*

- Disguise kit, Forgery kit, One type of gaming set, Thieves' tools, One type of musical instrument, One type of artisan’s tools, Vehicles (land), Herbalism kit, Navigator’s tools, Vehicles (water).
- Disguise kit, Forgery kit, One type of gaming set, Thieves' tools, One type of musical instrument, One type of artisan’s tools, Vehicles (land), Herbalism kit, Navigator’s tools, Vehicles (water)

##### Bard (3 tool proficiencies)

Taking your first class level in Bard grants a tool proficiency with three musical instruments of your choice..

- One type of musical instrument
- One type of musical instrument
- One type of musical instrument

#### At Level 2: 14 tool proficiencies

##### Artificer (2 tool proficiencies)

Taking your second class level as a multiclass into Artificer grants two tool proficiencies.

- Thieves' tools
- Tinker's tools

#### At Level 3: 15 tool proficiencies

##### Cleric (Forge) (1 tool proficiency)

Taking your third class level as a multiclass into Cleric grants access to a divine domain. Choosing the Forge domain grants a specific tool proficiency.

- Smith's tools

#### At Level 5: 16 tool proficiencies

##### Artificer (Any) (1 tool proficiency)

Taking your fourth and fifth class levels in Artificer and choosing to become a specialist in any of the options in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* grants you one additional tool proficiency. It will be a specific set of artisan's tools according to your subclass, except that if you already have that proficiency it instead becomes a proficiency in one type of artisan's tools.

- Alchemist's supplies, Smith's tools, Woodcarver's tools, or One type of artisan's tools

#### At Level 6: 19 tool proficiencies

##### Skilled (3 tool proficiencies)

Taking your sixth class level in Artificer grants you an **Ability Score Improvement**, for which you can instead choose a feat. Choosing the **Skilled** feat grants three tool proficiencies of your choice.

- Wildcard
- Wildcard
- Wildcard

#### At Level 9: 22 tool proficiencies

##### Rogue (Mastermind) (3 tool proficiencies)

Taking your seventh level in Rogue grants proficiency in thieves' tools, but it is wasted since you already knew how to use them from your Artificer levels. Taking your eighth and ninth class levels in Rogue and choosing the archetype Mastermind grants three tool proficiencies.

- Disguise kit
- Forgery kit
- One gaming set of your choice

#### At Level 12: 23 tool proficiencies

##### Monk (Drunken Master or Kensei) (1 tool proficiency)

Taking your tenth, eleventh, and twelfth class levels in Monk and choosing the monastic tradition of Way of the Kensei or the Way of the Drunken Master grants you one additional tool proficiency.

- Calligrapher's supplies, Painter's supplies, or Brewer's supplies

#### At Level 15: 24 tool proficiencies

##### Fighter (Battlemaster) (1 tool proficiency)

Taking your thirteenth, fourteenth, and fifteenth class levels in Fighter and choosing the archetype Battlemaster grants you one additional tool proficiency.

- One type of artisan's tools

---

Unfortunately, I am unaware of any new tool proficiencies granted by additional feats you're eligible for, or by any other classes or subclasses. Thus, we have capped out at **24 tool proficiencies)**!

### Example Proficiency List

1. Mason's tools
2. Leatherworker's tools
3. Weaver's tools
4. Carpenter's tools
5. Poisoner's kit
6. Navigator's tools
7. Cartographer's tools
8. Vehicles (land)
9. Vehicles (water)
10. Tinker's tools
11. Thieves' tools
12. Flute
13. Lute
14. Lyre
15. Smith's tools
16. Woodcarver's tools
17. Alchemist's supplies
18. Cook's utensils
19. Jeweler's tools
20. Disguise kit
21. Forgery kit
22. Dragonchess set
23. Painter's supplies
24. Calligrapher's supplies

Answer (score 6):

The question asks not to include the Artificer from Unearthed Arcana. Now that there is an official Artificer class from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, I will present this answer that includes the official Artificer.

(Note that much of my answer is borrowed from the other answers, I've just included a few levels of Artificer.)

### Through levelling only, you can have a  total of 19 tool proficiencies!

(This assumes musical instruments and gaming sets count as tool proficiencies; if not, then we're down to 15 tool proficiencies with this build; replacing the starting level in Bard with a starting level in Druid brings this up to 16 thanks to Herbalism Kit proficiency; alternatively, if you first level is in Artificer, you would also have one more choice of tool proficiency, so 16 is the maximum either way without musical instruments or gaming sets.)

#### Race

- Human, to gain access to the Prodigy feat;
- or Dwarf, for Mason's Tool or Brewer's Supplies (avoid Smith's Tools);
- or Vedalken (*Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, pg. 21), for a tool proficiency (thanks to [this comment](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/142442/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-tool-proficiencies-a-character-can-gain#comment362408_142447) for pointing that out);

(I'm avoiding Rock Gnome because we want Tinker's Tools from multiclassing into Artificer later; also note that by not picking Human, you miss out on one more from the Dragonmark below).

#### Dragonmark

- If we use Dragonmarks from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* (p. 45), you can pick the Variant Human: Mark of Making, which grants proficiency with a set of artisan's tools (via the ***Maker's Gift*** racial trait). This still counts as Human, so is still eligible for the Prodigy feat.

#### Background

- House Agent (from *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, p. 53), which gives you two proficiencies:

  - choosing House Ghallanda for Brewer's Supplies and Cook's Utensils, which works if we avoid Brewer's Supplies via Dwarf and avoid the Drunken Master for our Monk subclass;
  - choosing House Jorasco for Alchemist's Supplies and Herbalism Kit, which works if we choose Artillerist for our Artificer subclass instead of Alchemist (although Alchemist subclass lets us choose a different tool proficiency if we already have Alchemist's Supplies, so actually it doesn't matter which Artificer subclass we pick);
  - choosing House Thuranni for a Musical Instrument and Poisoner's Kit, which works if we are accepting Musical Instruments in our total;
  - choosing House Deneith, Lyrandar, Orien or Vadalis, which works if we are happy to include Vehicle proficiencies in our total;

#### Classes

- Bard 1 (taking our 1st level in Bard gets us three Musical Instrument proficiencies)
- Cleric 1 (Forge Domain, to gain Smith's Tools)
- Monk 3 (Drunken Master or Kensei; the former gives you Brewer's Supplies, so don't pick this and get Brewer's Supplies via Dwarf, and the latter gives you either Calligraphy Supplies or Painter's Supplies)
- Rogue 3 (Mastermind, which gets you Thieves' Tools from multiclassing into Rogue, then Disguise Kit, Forgery Kit, and a Gaming Set proficiency from Mastermind archetype)
- Fighter 3 (Battlemaster, which gives you one set of Artisan's Tools)
- Artificer 3 (we get Tinker's Tools from multiclassing into Artificer, also Thieves' Tools but we already have that via Rogue; we also get one more depending on our archetype, so Alchemist or Artillerist would be our best choice as that gets us Alchemist's Supplies or Woodcarver's Tools, which we don't have yet; if we did pick Battle Smith, we would already have Smith's Tools but it lets us pick a different tool proficiency if we already have Smith's Tools, so actually we can go with any Artificer subclass...)

#### Feats

- Skilled (from this we can gain proficiency with any 3 sets of tools)
- (If we chose Human as our race, the Prodigy feat will give us an extra proficiency, but that's already accounted for under Races above)

#### Total

So that's:

- 1 from race (picking "Human" assumes you take the Prodigy feat at some point)
- 1 from Dragonmark "Mark of Making" (assuming race is Human)
- 2 from background
- 3 from the Skilled feat
- 3 from Bard
- 1 from Forge Domain Cleric
- 1 from Drunken Master/Kensei Monk
- 4 from Mastermind Rogue
- 1 from Battlemaster Fighter
- 2 from Artificer (any subclass)

For a total of 19 tool proficiencies.

**Final Build:**
A "Mark of Making" Variant Human Bard 1/Cleric 1/Monk 3/Rogue 3/Fighter 3/Artificer 3, with the Prodigy and Skilled feats by taking two of those classes that we already have three levels in one level further.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the question just to make it clear that the official version of the Artificer is, indeed, valid for this question.

Comment: @Xirema Cool, thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of tool proficiencies is **17**
If musical instruments do not count, this maximum drops by 2.
If gaming sets do not count, this maximum drops by 1.

### The Character

Connor is a human with the Dragonmark of Making (in Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron) and these classes:

- Bard 1 ------------------------- (for musical instruments)
- Cleric (Forge from XGtE<sup>1</sup>) 1 --------------- (for smith's tools)
- Monk 4 ------------------------ (for 1 set of artisan tools or 1 musical instrument, 1 other set of tools, and the Prodigy feat from XGtE)
- Rogue (Mastermind from XGtE) 4 ------ (for thieves' tools, disguise kit, forgery kit, 1 gaming set, and the Skilled feat)
- Fighter (Battlemaster) 3 ---- (for 1 set of artisan tools)

<sup>1: XGtE refers to Xanathar's Guide to Everything</sup>

### The Tools

*Note: If musical instruments count, bard must be chosen at level 1. If musical instruments hold less than half the weight of other tool proficiencies, then choose Druid instead for* herbalism kit *and multiclass into bard later for one musical instrument*

Your Monastic Tradition can either be Drunken Master (for *brewer's supplies*) or Kensei (for *painter's supplies* or *calligrapher's supplies*), both from XGtE.

Your Roguish Archetype must be Mastermind unless gaming sets do not count in which case you can also choose Assassin (which replaces *forgery kit* with *poisoner's kit*)

Dragonmark of Making grants an artisan tool proficiency of your choice.

The Prodigy feat grants any tool proficiency of your choice, while the Skilled feat grants you 3 of your choice.

A customized background can grant any two proficiencies in tools according to the [Player's Handbook or [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/personality-and-background#CustomizingaBackground).

> To customize a background, you can replace one feature with any other one, choose any two skills, and choose a total of two tool proficiencies or languages from the sample backgrounds.

**Final tally:**

- 3 musical instruments of your choice **-or-** *herbalism kit* and 1 musical instrument of your choice
- *smith's tools*
- *disguise kit*
- *thieves' tools*
- *forgery kit* and 1 gaming set of your choice **-or-** *poisoner's kit*
- 3 sets of artisan tools of your choice **-or-** 2 sets of artisan tools and 1 musical instrument of your choice
- 6 of any tool of your choice

### Extra Stuff

- As a Mark of Making human, you can add a d4 to every ability check with a set of artisan tools.
- As a Rogue you can choose to gain Expertise in your thieves' tools.

### Temporary Proficiencies

If musical instruments do not count, an alternative build can acquire a different proficiency than *herbalism kit*, albeit temporarily, using the spell *magic jar* on an NPC in Waterdeep (spoilers):

> Thorvin Twinbeard in Waterdeep - Dragon Heist

If you forgo the level in Cleric and only get 3 levels in Monk and Rogue, you can replace Bard 1 with Wizard 11 to get *magic jar* which will both replace the *smith's tools* you would've gotten from cleric as well as grant you *mason's tools*. (You then use the wizard's Ability Score Increases to get the feats required).